# Instance of a class

Tags: java

I am really not sure whats happening in this code. Basically, in the current state, the code outputs `0`, but I am expecting the output to be `20`. I only get `20` when I use the other part of the OR which is currently commented out:

```
class Sum {
    int x, y;

    void setSum(int value1, int value2) {
        x = value1;
        y = value2;
    }

    int getSum() {
        return x + y;
    }
}

public class JavaBasics {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Sum newSum = new Sum();
        // newSum.setsum(10, 10); // 10 , 10 are the arguments
        //
        // OR
        new Sum().setsum(10, 10);

        System.out.println(new Sum().getSum());

        // OR
        // System.out.println(newSum.getSum());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're setting the sum of "instance 1" and you expect, that "instance 2" also has that value of "instance 1"? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I'm not understanding the two downvotes. Sure, it is a beginners' question, but it does show observations and expected behavior, and is easily a "teachable moment" for many beginners. It *might* make sense to have a better title, though.

Comment: It doesn't show why he thinks that two different references should share the same field values. Even a "beginner" should be able to understand that. Or I'm just expecting to much from "beginners" these days.

Comment: @Tom With a good answer, can be a very useful post for beginners

Comment: @Tom I'm going to be honest in that I was very confused by object instances (although my first OOP language was PHP's OOP implementation)

Comment: @hexafraction and **rpax** Well then remains the question (at least for me): should Stack Overflow allow questions about the absolute basic of a certain language or in other words should Stack Overflow rebuild a "[language xyz] tutorial book"? As far as I remember there is no consensus about that question among the users. Even the founders of this page had different opinions. So I guess every user should decide for himself/herself what to do with such questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are making two different instances of `Sum`, which have their own state, each time you use `new Sum()`.

Since you don't have a constructor the implicit default one is used, that sets x and y to both be zero when the object is constructed.

By storing it to the variable `Sum newSum`, you are creating a `Sum`, setting its x and y, and then reading back that *same* `Sum`.

You can declare some or all fields [static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) to make their value be accessible or shared across all instances. You can likewise make a `static` method that can be called without an instance of the class (e.g. `ClassName.staticMethod(foo, bar)`). Of course, since there is no instance it can't directly access non-static fields.

Comment: Rolled back. The OP already knows how to make it 20, just not why that happens.

Comment: Yeah,  I missed the commented out part

Comment: @JuanMendes No problem, it happens :)

Comment: I'd like to add that although using static here might work (depending on what the OP does with those) but I'd strongly advise against that - unless you know what you're doing and there are good reasons for that, and it looks like the OP currently doesn't exactly know what he's doing here. :)

Comment: Thanks for clearing the confusion cloud. Things are very clear now, also I tried with the static method. Thanks again.    Someone might be thinking it's a very basic question. May be for you. I hold a Engineering degree in Electronics and don't have much idea apart from C programming. not even C++

Comment: @user2381536 I'll be honest, I had similar confusion like this when I began.

Answer (score 3):

You are referring two different object to set values and get values back.

```
 new Sum().Setsum(10, 10);  // object 1
 System.out.println(new Sum().getSum()); // object 2
```

you are setting value in first step. But you are referring some other new instance to get values back, There is no values set to this new instance.

Make sure you are referring to same object then you will get expected result.

```
 Sum sum=new Sum(); // creating a instance
 sum.Setsum(10, 10); // setting value
 System.out.println(sum.getSum()); // getting value back from same instance
```

Answer (score 1):

You print out

`new Sum().getSum()`

This creates a new Instance of your Class Sum, which of course has the default values 0 and 0.

I guess you want something like:

`Sum mySum = new Sum().setSum(10,10)`
`System.out.println(mySum)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Object is not hold by any reference.

```
new Sum().Setsum(10, 10);
```

When you used this syntax then a object(memory location) is created and along with a set method is called. but we do not have any reference to point to the memory.

```
system.out.println(new Sum().getSum());
```

When you used this syntax then a new object(memory location) is created and along with get method is called. this object does not have any relationship with first one.

```
new Sum().Setsum(10, 10).getSum();
```

You can use this syntax if you do not want to keep reference.

I hope it helps you to understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Sum().Setsum(10, 10); // Object 1
 System.out.println(new Sum().getSum()); //Object 2
```

In first Object creation, you are passing `10` and `10` to `setSum()` method. Those values are assigned to `x` and `y` respectively inside `setSum()` method. In your code declared `x` an `y` as a instance variables.

In second object, you are calling `gerSum()` method . returning  `x+y`. They already initialized with 10 and 10 by using **Object1**. That's why its returning `20`.

Solution:

```
Sum s1 = new Sum();
 s1.setSum(10,10); 
s1.getSum(); // using same object s1
```

Output:

```
20
```

Comment: `In your code declared x an y as a global variables.` - no, they are instance variables not global.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Sum {
    int x, y;
    void setSum(int value1, int value2) {
        x = value1;
        y = value2;
    }
    int getSum() {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

When you define any class nothing will happen in memory, not a single allocation. Memory allocation will be based on instances you defined for that class like,

```
Sum s1 = new Sum(); 
Sum s2 = new Sum();
```

Here two memory blocks will be created, in each block there are two variables say x and y. Remember instance variables bounded with object and methods are commonly shared by all the objects.

So when you called `s1.getSum()` then it will gives you x and y of s1 object because you have called this method using s1 (invoking object is accessible inside the method).

So if you want to store value in variables then you need to create object for it, `new Sum()` is having single line scope after execution get completed it will not accessible.

```
Sum s1=new Sum(); // Create an instance
s1.Setsum(10, 10); // Invoking set value method using s1 object so 10, 10 will be stored in x and y of s1.
System.out.println(s1.getSum()); // display x and y of s1 object.
```

Answer (score -1):

Of course it would be 0. You use different instances of Sum class.
Change your main method to something like this:

Sum sunObj = new Sum();
sumObj.Setsum(10, 10);

System.out.println(sumObj.getSum());

Comment: Please take the time to formulate a **complete** answer (including formatting) before hitting the send button.

Comment: Plead read this help page about formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score -1):

You are not getting the result as 20 because .
When u r calling using anonymous object ..that object having no reference so that u can not point to that object ..
Means whenever u r using only new sum().setsum() ..that time it is setting the value .
But when u are trying to the get u r calling by new sum().getsum().
Which is new object..it is not pointing to the same instance what  u used for setting the sum..
So that's why u r getting 0.
So better to use reference .
Means sum newSum= new sum().
And do the setting and getting by using that reference variable newSum.get Sum();
Thank u

Comment: Plead read this help page about formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thanks Tom for ur advice